# Why would WSASendMsg return WSAEINVAL for a socket returned from accept()?

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock2

I have a Windows server app which does

- WSAStartup(), obviously
- listen() on TCP port X
- accept() an incoming connection
- ioctlsocket() the socket into nonblocking mode
- try to reply with WSASendMsg

I receive WSAEINVAL error code, which supposedly means:
'The socket has not been bound with bind, or the socket was not created with the overlapped flag.'

In this case it makes no sense to call bind(), since the socket is already connected with local and remote addresses. And the socket was definitely not created with the overlapped flag either.

So what is the real reason I get the error that escaped that line of documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICWO: Because I'm using `accept()` to listening for a TCP socket connection request, what accept returns me is a *connection-oriented socket*. So I have to use `WSASend()` instead of `WSASendMsg()`. MSDN docs do have this tidbit which eventually tipped me off to where I was going wrong:

> The WSASendMsg function can only be used with datagrams and raw
>   sockets.

In other words, `WSASendMsg()` is ONLY intended for use in *connectionless* scenarios like UDP, ICMP, or any other raw sockets where you are authoring your own packets.

(Probably, I could also have used `WSASendTo()` instead:)

> On a connection-oriented socket, the lpTo and iToLen parameters are ignored; 
>   in this case, the WSASendTo is equivalent to WSASend.

Comment: MSDN's wording seems sloppy. It should say 'datagram *sockets* or raw sockets'.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, it saved me ripping my hair out. To clarify something though: documentation say at the very top that *"The `WSASendMsg` function sends data and optional control information from connected and unconnected sockets."*? Is "connected" here referring to raw sockets? Because I totally thought it meant "connected" meant you can use it on connection-oriented sockets...

Comment: @user541686 welcome! By connected, I just meant that I've accepted a TCP connection request, i.e. its a stream socket connection. Let me update my answer to clarify...